# Media session's artwork not showing up

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to build a simple music player. Media session metadata has been easy to deal with and is working fine. However, I now tried to set up the artwork, with code inspired by Museeks:

```js
const cover = this.getCover(this.playback.album.coverPath);

// Setup media session metadata
let metadata = {
    title: this.playback.track.title,
    album: this.playback.album.title,
    artist: this.playback.album.artist,
    artwork: cover? [{ src: cover }] : null
};
navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata(metadata);


getCover(coverPath) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(coverPath, { encoding: 'base64' });
    const format = path.extname(coverPath).substr(1);
    return `data:${format};base64,${data}`;
}
```

The code runs without errors, but no image appears. On the console, typing `navigator.mediaSession.metadata.artwork[0].src` results in the correct string, since pasting it as the source of an `img` element displays the correct image.

**Update:** This does work on Windows, so it's likely a problem with Ubuntu. I am probably going to create an issue on electron's GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

The format needs to be a mime type like "image/jpeg", not a file extension

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, that doesn't solve the problem. I still don't know what to do. I know that Museeks does the exact same thing and it works in my OS. Perhaps I'm going to ask for some help there :)

Comment: I'm building a music player in Electron too, and this navigator media session is very weird... I had similar bug recently and I started using Blobs for artwork images, and now it runs more smoothly and fast. Maybe you should try this

Comment: You can't imagine how thrilled I was while reading this comment. I think you are the first person I'm talking to who is actually doing the same thing as I am... Well, let's get to business: I tried Blobs, but they don't work. It's a similar situation as the one I described: no errors thrown and no image showing up. Can I see your code? Actually, I would like to see the whole project, if it is available :)

Comment: If you want to take a look, mine can be found [here](https://github.com/m7kra/Musicly). I'm also making a [website](https://m7kra.github.io/Musicly/) for it.